# Make an x-axis labels visible

Tags: vb.net

I have developed a mschart in vb.net that brings in data as date string, MMM dd yyyy, and two money values. The date data is to be the x-axis with an interval of 30, but does not show on the chart while the y-axis does.  What can I do to make the x-axis labels visible?

Comment: Could you please give some more information like some part of related code

Comment: Here is some of the related code: for i = 0 to  jk: if Dailygrid

Comment: Series("Series1").Point.AddXY(dailygrid(0,i),dailygrid(j,i): Series("Series2).Point.AddY(Contstant): next i: k=i+1: for i=k to jk: Series(Series2).Point.AddXY(Dailygrid(0,i),Constant): next i